# How to find the nth last non-empty cell in a row, on another worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to find the third last non-empty cell in a row, on another worksheet, and return its value in the current cell. I am able to obtain the second last non-empty value, but not the third last.

I have tried using offset, index and lookup as shown below.

```
'Attempt 1
=(INDEX('Ontario - Monthly'!3:3,MATCH(9^99,'Ontario - Monthly'!3:3)))

'Attempt 2
=LOOKUP(2,1/(('Ontario - Monthly'!AO3:NH3<>"")),'Ontario -Monthly'!AN3:NH3)

'Attempt 3
=OFFSET('Ontario - Monthly'!AN3,'Ontario - Monthly'!AN3:XFD3-3,1)
```

Comment: If all rows in the column you are testing are filled, you can use: `=INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)-B1)`, where `A:A` is the column being tested and `B1` contains n

Comment: what if they are not all filled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!1:1,AGGREGATE(14,6,1/(LEN(Sheet2!1:1)>0)*COLUMN(Sheet2!1:1),3))
                                                                          ^
```

Change the `3` to `n` if you want a different `nth last`

[image]